# Opencart. Show the filter "Out of Stock Status" in the Product List admin panel

Tags: opencart

Friend, please help to add the filter "Out of Stock" in the Product List admin panel.

[image]

What is done:

Add in product_list

```
      <div class="form-group">            
        <label class="control-label" for="input-stock-status">{{ entry_stock_status }}</label>
          <select name="stock_status_id" id="input-stock-status" class="form-control">
            {% for stock_status in stock_statuses %}
            {% if stock_status.stock_status_id == stock_status_id %}
            <option value="{{ stock_status.stock_status_id }}" selected="selected">{{ stock_status.name }}</option>
            {% else %}
            <option value="{{ stock_status.stock_status_id }}">{{ stock_status.name }}</option>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </select>
      </div>
```

In the column where `{{ product.status }}` i added `{{ product.stock_status }}`, but i understand that this is wrong :(

Now need to add some information to the controller or model?

Comment: An appeal to the one who put the minus in reputation. If you are ready to help only for money, then write about it. Why are not your actions so beautiful? Or do you just like to humiliate people? I know how to do this with the example of other filters, but I do not know how to add the variable status_stock or status_stock_id to be visible in the product list. It would be better to prompt how to act than to be a hater. Friends, let's be kinder to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In admin/controller/catalog/product.php

**around line no. 259
add:-**

```
if (isset($this->request->get['filter_stock_status'])) {
        $filter_stock_status = $this->request->get['filter_stock_status'];
    } else {
        $filter_stock_status = '';
    }
$this->load->model('localisation/stock_status');

    $data['stock_statuses'] = $this->model_localisation_stock_status->getStockStatuses();
```

**add** (**everywhere after filter_status(important)**):

```
if (isset($this->request->get['filter_stock_status'])) {
        $url .= '&filter_stock_status=' . $this->request->get['filter_stock_status'];
    }
```

**after:**

```
if (isset($this->request->get['filter_status'])) {
        $url .= '&filter_status=' . $this->request->get['filter_status'];
    }
```

**add:**

```
'filter_stock_status' => $filter_stock_status,
```

**after:**

```
'filter_quantity' => $filter_quantity,
        'filter_status'   => $filter_status,
```

**add:**

```
$data['filter_stock_status'] = $filter_stock_status;
```

**after:**

```
$data['filter_status'] = $filter_status;
```

**in product_list.twig:**

**add :**

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="input-stock-status">{{ entry_stock_status }}</label>
          <select name="filter_stock_status" id="input-stock-status" class="form-control">
             <option value="" {% if filter_stock_status == "" %} {{ 'selected' }} {% endif %}></option>
            {% for stock_status in stock_statuses %}
                <option value="{{ stock_status.stock_status_id}}" {% if filter_stock_status == stock_status.stock_status_id %} {{ 'selected' }} {% endif %}>{{ stock_status.name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
            <option value="-1" {% if filter_stock_status == -1 %} {{ 'selected' }} {% endif %}>All except out of stock</option>
          </select>
        </div>
```

**add:**

```
var filter_stock_status = $('select[name=\'filter_stock_status\']').val();

if (filter_stock_status !== '') {
    url += '&filter_stock_status=' + encodeURIComponent(filter_stock_status);
}
```

**after :**

```
var filter_status = $('select[name=\'filter_status\']').val();

if (filter_status !== '') {
    url += '&filter_status=' + encodeURIComponent(filter_status);
}
```

**in admin/model/catalog/product.php :**

**add:**

```
if (isset($data['filter_stock_status']) && $data['filter_stock_status'] !== '' ) {
        if($data['filter_stock_status'] == -1){
            $sql .= " AND p.stock_status_id <> 5";
        }elseif($data['filter_stock_status'] != -1){    
            $sql .= " AND p.stock_status_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_stock_status'] . "'";
        }
    }
```

in getProducts function

**before :**

```
$sql .= " GROUP BY p.product_id";
```

**add:**

```
if (isset($data['filter_stock_status']) && $data['filter_stock_status'] !== '' ) {
        if($data['filter_stock_status'] == -1){
            $sql .= " AND p.stock_status_id <> 5";
        }elseif($data['filter_stock_status'] != -1){    
            $sql .= " AND p.stock_status_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_stock_status'] . "'";
        }
    }
```

in getTotalProducts($data = array()) function

**before :**

```
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Comment: Radhika, I did exactly as you said, but I get an error when choosing a filter `Undefined variable: url` points to a line `$sql .= " AND p.stock_status_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_stock_status'] . "'";` and when choosing "All exept..." points to a line `$sql .= " AND p.stock_status_id <> 5";`

Comment: @VeroN, Please check once again if you put all code proper as I have tested this and it works fine.

Comment: Radhika, please check the correctness of my code in this file - [link](http://dropmefiles.com/sX40d).

Comment: @VeroN, Please check this https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PCeHhQW471C21BsgBeVrDccDlU0CImsM?usp=sharing

Comment: Radhika, i found my mistake, thank you! I noticed that when select the status and filter it, it does not remain selected in the field, ie the field remains empty and does not indicate which filter is currently selected. Is it possible to fix this moment?

Comment: Can you please send me view file?

Comment: Radhika, for testing, i completely replaced my files with those where you made a change, but that did not help. Do you have this field is not empty? The filter works, but when I apply a filter, that field becomes empty. Please look gif image - [link](https://s6.postimg.cc/g8fl027oh/2018-04-26_17-22-08.gif).

Comment: I need to check .twig file

Comment: Radhika, i think this is due to the absence of the function `selected ="selected"`. Is it possible to add this function to this code?

Comment: Big thanks, It is amazing, Radhika. And the last question on this topic: to display the status(without "id=5") in one of the columns, what variables should be added to the 'model' and 'controller'? I'm trying to do it in the same way as for "catalog", but it does not fit. In "admin" comes out so need another method.

Comment: you need to add stock_status_id and stock_status in both.

Comment: Radhika, i did the following: add in "admin/controller/catalog/product.php" add `if($result['stock_status_id'] == 5){
    $my text = '';
    }else{
    $my text = $result['stock_status'];
    }` before `$data['products'][] = array(`, further add `'my text'       => $my text,` after `$data['products'][] = array(`, but i still get an error "_Undefined index: stock_status_". :( And help please find a place to paste `'stock_status_id'  => $query->row['stock_status_id'],` in "admin/model/catalog/product.php"

Comment: You can't get stock_status but you can fetch stock_status_id in controller and no need to add stock_status_id in model.

Comment: Radhika, i can not understand why i get the message: "_Undefined index: stock_status_". What am I doing wrong? Maybe I'm putting it in the wrong place?

Comment: @Veron, as stock_staus is not being fetch by query from database

Comment: Hello, @Radhika. You asked to be reminded of me after the 15th. Tell me please, are you already free? You can reply in our chat discussion.

Comment: @VeroN, Please say how can I help you?

Comment: Radhika, tell please, do you appeared free time?

Comment: @VeroN Yes Please say

Comment: Radhika, I'm talking about our last conversation with you here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168828. Please respond in that chat room to reopen it, if you forgot what we were talking about, I'll remind you again.

Comment: Radhika, please re-open our chat chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168828 I will write you scenario again.

Comment: As chat is not enabled can you please explain here?

Comment: Radhika, in the comments there are very few characters for the text :( You have a high rating, you can open this discussion again simply by answering there, or can create a new discussion and send me a link to it?

Comment: @VeroN, sorry but I am still not authorized to start new discussion.

Comment: Radhika, please follow the link https://drive.google.com/open?id=1x8nTEPR3cCQ2sMhTlwARK54QfLzRDkq5

Comment: Radhika, please do not be silent, i really need your help.